# Cython wrapping dll, Cannot convert 'long *' to Python object

Tags: dll, cython

Ive written a ctypes wrapper over an instrument dll and it works fine.  What id like to do is call several functions of the dll inside of one cython call to speed up the set of calls that are in a critical loop.  Im not sure how much improvement ill see, but i figured its worth a shot.

I have created the the following pxy file. Upon compilation, i get the

> Cannot convert 'long *' to Python object

I think i know what this means, im just not sure how to fix it.

from test.pyx:

```
cdef extern from "path to Include\\foo.h":
     int foo_func(char*,short,short,char*,long*)

def testFoo(cython.char * var1,cython.short var2,cython.short var3,cython.char * var4, cython.p_long var5):
     foo.foo_func(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5)
```

I believe that i need to define/cast a pointer to var5, just not sure where as defining as cdef cython.p_long var5 gets a redeclaration error.

Ive tried separate pxd and pyx files, but read elsewhere that might not be needed in simple cases, so i present the simpler case here.

Obviously, im not very good at cython, but im trying to learn.

Any help is appreciated!